# Get image name from Facebook image url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, open-uri

I want to use Facebook profile image as the profile image for my site when the user logins via Facebook. I am using omniauth gem for Facebook login. After login, omniauth gives Facebook response in the form of a Hash which looks like this:

```
{
  "user_info" => {
                   "last_name" => "..........", 
                   "image" => "http://graph.facebook.com/100002356868026/picture?type=square",
                   "first_name" => "........", 
                   "email" => "xxxxx@xxx.xxx"
                  },
  "uid" => "..........."
}
```

Here, I can access the image url using `request.omniauth["user_info"]["image"]` and can save it using

```
require 'open-uri'
image_url = request.omniauth["user_info"]["image"]
image_data = open(image_url).read
File.open("image.png", "wb") { |file| file << image_data }
```

I want to get the image name from the url. But, the Facebook url doesnt contain the name (It is a link which redirects to another page whose url contains the image name). How can I parse the image name from the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get the final image name from the url. The image is stored at a content delivery network (CDN), which delivers the image not by facebook id, but by some other index.

Why would you want the final image name anyway? You can obtain the image by following the image parameter you quoted, it will return the user's image data (if available, else a dummy image is returned) directly.

If you want to store the images on your server, you most likely would choose your own naming scheme.

Important: Please check the facebook developer terms carefully! Storing user images on your server may violate these terms.

I would recommend not to process the image on your server at all but to just include the image parameter as it is in your html image tag, if possible.

Comment: yea...my concern is I want to use this image as profile picture..in some places, the image is being resized and shown..so if I get the image, I could resize the image..but i realize it is a bad idea..i should rather use image parameter in the html image tag and specify width and height in html.

Comment: i would advise this. facebook provides user images in four different sizes, so you probably will be able to get a appropriate sized image. in your question you used "type=square". instead of "square" you can use "small", "normal" or "large".